# Cocoa swift load ViewController and and storyboard view from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have created a `SideBar()` class which creates a `NSView` with various buttons.

I instantiate my `sideBar()` in my `AppDelegate` by doing

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    sideBarView.setupSideBarView()
    sideBarView.menuButton.action = #selector(self.NewMenuButton(_:))

}
@objc func NewMenuButton(_ sender: NSButton) {

}
```

In my Initial ViewController I then present my `sideBar` in the following way:

```
view.addSubview(sideBarView.getView())
```

With the press of menuButton I would like the function in the App Delegate to load and present a new storyboard view with its ViewController.

Can this be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue giving my second ViewController a storyboard id. 
Then, through the AppDelegate function:

```
 let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: Bundle.main)
 let mainPageController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "test") as! SecondViewController
 NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentViewController = mainPageController
```